# Can i use Google Search API to search pages by html source?

Tags: set, limits

Can I use Google Search API to search pages by html source? I want to make a different search engine which will set limits on the engine based on the code of each site. For example, suppose I want to set a parameter which will exclude sites which contain headings. Is this possible?